# I have two different table having some common text, How can I get it out

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, amazon-redshift

Example:

This is first table

```
column1            username
ajay|buln|khera|   110040062
ajay|shara|khera   110040082
ajay|abhay|bul     110040046
```

This is 2nd table

```
column2     username
buln        110040062
buln        110040082
ajay|bhav   110040046
```

I want this as a result:

```
column1            column2    anything common
ajay|buln|khera|   buln       TRUE
ajay|shara|khera   buln       FALSE
ajay|abhay|bul     ajay|bhav  TRUE
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really should take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand what we expect from our users and their posts. In its current form I see no other option to [down vote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question). Please [edit] your question into shape.

Comment: Ajay,   SQL tables are normally joined thru the Primary key, where at least one table is involved in the join via primary key, and the other usually via foreign key.    From what you have given us, there is no way we can know what your table keys are.  Further, the data looks de-normalized.  Are you really putting multiple values in one column ?    That will make join queries impossible or at best unreliable.   Please provide DDL  and  precise data from your tables, or we really don't have a chance to assist you.

Comment: user name is primary key. and thanx for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As written in comment your tables are not normalized and it is not the right way to concatenate multiple values in a field.

However if you really have to manage multiples values in your columns. I suggest the use of user defined functions. here is my solution.

First the database creation script:

```
create database stackAjay;
use stackAjay;

create table tableOne
(column1 varchar(50),
username INT(15) primary key);

create table tableTwo
(column1 varchar(50),
username INT(15)  primary key);

insert into tableOne(column1,username)
values ('ajay|buln|khera|',110040062),('ajay|shara|khera',110040082),    ('ajay|abhay|bul',110040046);

insert into tableTwo(column1,username)
values ('buln', 110040062),('buln',110040082),('ajay|bhav',110040046);
```

Then we will create three user defined function
The first one count the amount of character in your text. here we will use it to count the "|"

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `countCharInString`(myString text,     myChar char) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
RETURN (select length(myString)-length(replace(myString,myChar,'')));
END
```

The second UDF will be used to manage your text with separator as an array.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `SPLIT_STR`(
x VARCHAR(255),
delim VARCHAR(12),
pos INT
) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
   LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
   delim, '')
```

Finally the third UDF will compare each cells of your "text" array and if at least one word is in both text array, it will return true.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`rroot`@`localhost` FUNCTION `hasSomethingInCommom`(text1     text, text2 text) RETURNS varchar(5) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
Declare amountOfWordText1 int;
Declare amountOfWordText2 int;
Declare currentWord1 int;
Declare currentWord2 int;

Set amountOfWordText1=countCharInString(text1,'|')+1;
Set amountOfWordText2=countCharInString(text2,'|')+1;
Set currentWord1=1;
Set currentWord2=1;

while (currentWord1<=amountOfWordText1) do
        Set currentWord2=1;
        while (currentWord2<=amountOfWordText2) do
            if     (SPLIT_STR(text1,'|',currentWord1)=SPLIT_STR(text2,'|',currentWord2)) Then
                RETURN 'TRUE';
            END IF;
            Set currentWord2=currentWord2+1;
        END WHILE;
        Set currentWord1=currentWord1+1;
END WHILE;
RETURN 'FALSE';
END
```

Finally to compare the column of both tables you could do.

```
select tableOne.column1, tableTwo.column1,hasSomethingInCommom(tableOne.column1, tableTwo.column1) as `in   common`
from tableOne 
left outer join tabletwo 
ON tableOne.username=tableTwo.username
```

As previously said, it would be easier for you to manage this with a good database design.

[image: output]

Comment: if it is what you want @Ajay, please upvote or mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,,,  I'll give it a shot but this is just a guess.

```
Select  Table1.Column1
,   Table2.Column2
,   Case  when Table2.Column1 like '%Table2.Column1%' 
    Then 'TRUE' 
    Else 'FALSE' 
    End Case
From    Table1
Left Outer  
Join    Table2
    On  Table2.username = Table1.username
```

Comment: True and False is more important here.
because in first table column1 is allowable access to that username and in table 2, column 2 is the person who accessed.

Comment: I want to know that person who accessed is in list or not